# Sending large amounts of text to mySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm running into an issue where I'm unable to type out text in a textbox, have a large amount of it, and then deploy it to my mySQL table. Though I am able to "paste" a large amount of text in the textarea and deploy it. And that properly saves to the mySQL. It dosen't realy make any sense to me!

**index.php**

```
<?php
include('../config.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> </title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="post.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="title" value=""><br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Message" name="post">
</textarea><br>
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php $script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone'))){echo date("F j, Y");}?>"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="timestamp" value="<?php $script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone'))){echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");}?>"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="send">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**post.php**

```
<?php 
$title=$_POST['title']; 
$post=$_POST['post'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
$timestamp=$_POST['timestamp'];
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("root") or die(mysql_error()) ;  
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `posts` VALUES ('$title', '$post', '$date', '$timestamp')") ; 
header('Location: /');
?>
```

**SQL (Table is called "posts")**

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `title` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `post` varchar(50000) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Don't mind "date" and "timestamp". The data that is posted into the table for those rows are all text not numerical.**
I'm not sure why i'm unable to write out large amounts of text in "post" and save them to the mySQL! I'ved tried BLOB, LONGTEXT, and TEXT. But nothing has worked... And ideas?

Comment: Use `TEXT` field type instead of `VARCHAR(50000)`

Comment: In bold it states I have done that... didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's `varchar()` field allows over 65k bytes. The problem is there is a limit to the number of bytes that PHP can handle when you're uploading. You can change this with `.htaccess` provided you are allowed overrides or in `php.ini`. You would change the [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size):

```
#set max post size
php_value post_max_size 5M
```

or

```
<?php

   ini_set('post_max_size','5M');

?>
```

Comment: @absoluteer I just tried both, but nothing seemed to work. I'm using Heroku as my hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

I think **should be avoid to insert strings of more than 16MB**, it would generate an "Allowed memory size of XXXXXXXX bytes exhausted".

A solution could be compress the string with PHP before insert to MySQL:
**$compressed = gzcompress($contents, 9);** // 9 is maximum compression

That way, **you can reduce from 32MB to 3MB**, a log file, for example, so it can be handled correctly in MySQL insertion.

**To descompress, gzuncompress()** will do the trick.

Comment: Even better, compress directly with MySQL as value:
COMPRESS('" . mysqli_escape_string($link, $contents) . "') on a field defined as MEDIUMBLOB (16MB) or LONGBLOB (4GB)